# Have two controls set the visibility of another control

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm

Sorry for the title, I just don't know how to explain it in one sentence.

So here is my goal: I need to have a boolean in my ViewModel define the visibility for a control (border).

I know I can achieve this with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter, but there is a little more to it. I want a button on my UI to be shown if the control is not visible. Once that button is pushed, then I want the boolean in my ViewModel to be TRUE and then I want the control to be visible and the button that was just pushed to be collapsed. Once that control is visible, I would like a button within that recently visible control to make the control collapsed and then make the original button visible.

Basically, there are two buttons: 1 to make visible (then collapse itself) and the other is to collapse its container and then make the first button visible.

I am trying to do all this with MVVM so if I can avoid code behind in my View that would be ideal!

Comment: How are you handling the button clicks? An ICommand on your ViewModel? If so, just set the boolean property to true or false respective to the "execute" method for the command you're calling. For example, you press the first button (to show the border), and in the execute method on your viewModel, set your boolean to TRUE. In your XAML, bind the visibility of the Border to that same boolean property, and use the BooleanToVisibiltyConverter like you already suggested.

Comment: I will take a stab at that. Yes I am using ICommand in my ViewModel. Wouldnt I need some sort of OppositeBooleanToVisibility converter though? So when my flag is true, that means to hide/collapse the other control?

Comment: Yes, you'll need exactly that. You'll use your BoolToVisibility converter on the border and the opposite converter on the button that's outside of the border (the one used to initiate the border's visibility)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't done the Opposite converter yet but your suggestion for the ICommand worked awesome. I'll mark ya as answer if ya post an answer to the question rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using ICommands on your viewmodel, this should work...Assume your commands are "ShowBorderCommand" and "HideBorderCommand" and the property on your viewmodel is "ShowBorder"

```
<ConverterNamespace:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
<ConverterNamespace:ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToCollapse"/>

<Border Visibility="{Binding ShowBorder, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <Button Command="{Binding HideBorderCommand}"/>
</Border>

<Button Command="{Binding ShowBorderCommand}" Visbility="{Binding ShowBorder, Converter={StaticResource BoolToCollapse}}"/>
```

Comment: Just FYI, I used one ICommand and passed in a parameter to show/hide. That way I didn't need two commands.

Answer (score 1):

My [WPF Converters library](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/) has a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66714#1380795) that allows reverse conversions, as well as allowing the use of `Hidden` instead of `Collapsed`:

```
<con:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter" IsReversed="True"/>
<Button Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```